# Libgdx | Android | Can I get away with using non-pow2 textures for a simple game?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I am making a game with libgdx. Can I get away with using non-pow2 textures? They will only be for the menus. I'm less worried about it effecting performance and more worried if it may be incompatible with some android/ios devices? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you can't use mip mapping or texture wrapping.

Comment: I would just add to Tenfour04's comment that not being able to use mip mapping is a big deal because the variations in screen resolutions across devices are so huge. A lack of texture wrapping for 2D menus is not a big loss.

Answer (score 1):

I know two ways for it:

1) Pack your images to texture packer:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer
https://code.google.com/archive/p/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/

2) Rewrite you non-pow2 texture to pow2 texture like this:

```
public Texture getTexture() {

    // Gdx.app.log("WWW", "url: " + urlString);
    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.length);
    final int originalWidth = pixmap.getWidth();
    final int originalHeight = pixmap.getHeight();
    int width = MathUtils.nextPowerOfTwo(pixmap.getWidth());
    int height = MathUtils.nextPowerOfTwo(pixmap.getHeight());

    int deltaX = (int) ((width - originalWidth) / 2f);
    int deltaY = (int) ((height - originalHeight) / 2f);

    final Pixmap potPixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, pixmap.getFormat());
    potPixmap.drawPixmap(pixmap, deltaX, deltaY, 0, 0, pixmap.getWidth(), pixmap.getHeight());
    pixmap.dispose();
    Texture texture = new Texture(potPixmap);
    potPixmap.dispose();
    return texture;
}
```